# Nested Loop to collect Results from multiple Functions into a seperate DataFrame Challenge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Simplicity is key and I try to erase my thoughts and just explain my vision of what the code is doing and not write the code in this response.

So, I have a DF with numerous columns.

1st I loop, to Groupby column Market_Data = MD
To create 21 MD groups.

Each group has 13 Timeframes = TF, so I group by Column Timeframe = TF to get 13 TF groups for each 21 MD, Market_Data groups.

I have 5 or more "def functions" that have a pass/fail result.

I want the "Sum Count" = SC of how many pass for each Timeframe so the results of a Dataframe would look like below......

```
           TF1     TF2       TF3 -......... TF13
   MD1     SC1     SC2       SC3            SC13
   MD2     SC1     SC2       SC3            SC13
   MD3     SC1     SC2       SC3            SC13

   etc.........
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understood your question, but here's a start point for a discussion.

First, let's start with a sample input data:

```py
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123) # set seed for reproduction
sample_data = np.random.rand(21*13).reshape(21,13) * 10 # sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data, columns=[f'TF{i}' for i in range(1,14)], index=[f'MD{i}' for i in range(1,22)]) # dataframe
```

That's how our sample dataframe looks like:

```
           TF1       TF2       TF3       TF4       TF5       TF6       TF7       TF8       TF9      TF10      TF11      TF12      TF13
MD1   6.964692  2.861393  2.268515  5.513148  7.194690  4.231065  9.807642  6.848297  4.809319  3.921175  3.431780  7.290497  4.385722
MD2   0.596779  3.980443  7.379954  1.824917  1.754518  5.315514  5.318276  6.344010  8.494318  7.244553  6.110235  7.224434  3.229589
MD3   3.617887  2.282632  2.937140  6.309761  0.921049  4.337012  4.308628  4.936851  4.258303  3.122612  4.263513  8.933892  9.441600
MD4   5.018367  6.239530  1.156184  3.172855  4.148262  8.663092  2.504554  4.830343  9.855598  5.194851  6.128945  1.206287  8.263408
MD5   6.030601  5.450680  3.427638  3.041208  4.170222  6.813008  8.754568  5.104223  6.693138  5.859366  6.249035  6.746891  8.423424
MD6   0.831950  7.636828  2.436664  1.942230  5.724570  0.957125  8.853268  6.272490  7.234164  0.161292  5.944319  5.567852  1.589596
MD7   1.530705  6.955295  3.187664  6.919703  5.543832  3.889506  9.251325  8.416700  3.573976  0.435915  3.047681  3.981857  7.049588
MD8   9.953585  3.559149  7.625478  5.931769  6.917018  1.511275  3.988763  2.408559  3.434560  5.131282  6.666246  1.059085  1.308950
MD9   3.219806  6.615643  8.465062  5.532573  8.544525  3.848378  3.167879  3.542647  1.710818  8.291126  3.386708  5.523701  5.785515
MD10  5.215331  0.026881  9.883454  9.053416  2.076359  2.924894  5.200102  9.019114  9.836309  2.575421  5.643590  8.069687  3.943701
MD11  7.310730  1.610690  6.006986  8.658645  9.835216  0.793658  4.283473  2.045429  4.506365  5.477636  0.933267  2.968608  9.275842
MD12  5.690037  4.574120  7.535260  7.418622  0.485790  7.086974  8.392433  1.659379  7.809979  2.865366  3.064698  6.652615  1.113922
MD13  6.648724  8.878568  6.963113  4.403279  4.382144  7.650961  5.656420  0.849042  5.826711  8.148437  3.370664  9.275766  7.507170
MD14  5.740638  7.516440  0.791490  8.593891  8.215041  9.098717  1.286312  0.817801  1.384156  3.993787  4.243069  5.622184  1.222435
MD15  2.013995  8.116443  4.679876  8.079382  0.074264  5.515927  9.319321  5.821755  2.060957  7.177576  3.789858  6.683839  0.293197
MD16  6.359004  0.321979  7.447807  4.729130  1.217544  5.426359  0.667744  6.533649  9.960863  7.693973  5.737741  1.026353  6.998341
MD17  6.611679  0.490971  7.922993  5.187166  4.258677  7.881872  4.115692  4.810263  1.816288  3.213189  8.455330  1.869037  4.172911
MD18  9.890345  2.365998  9.168323  9.183975  0.912963  4.636527  5.022163  3.136690  0.473395  2.416856  0.955296  2.382499  8.077911
MD19  8.949783  0.432229  3.019468  9.805822  5.395048  6.263094  0.055454  4.849094  9.883285  3.751855  0.970382  4.619088  9.630045
MD20  3.418306  7.989227  7.988463  2.082483  4.433677  7.156013  4.105198  1.910070  9.674943  6.507504  8.654599  0.252424  2.669058
MD21  5.020711  0.674486  9.930333  2.364624  3.742922  2.140119  1.054459  2.324798  3.006101  6.344423  2.812348  3.622768  0.059428
```

Now let's define some functions for applying to each timeframe, returning `True` or `False` (pass or not, respectively). Also, we place them all into a list:

```py
def sum_greater_than_100(series):
    return series.sum() > 100

def mean_greater_than_5(series):
    return series.mean() > 5

def std_less_than_3(series):
    return series.std() < 3

my_list_of_functions = [sum_greater_than_100, mean_greater_than_5, std_less_than_3]
```

We can apply our functions using [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) dataframe method:

```py
df_pass = df.agg(my_list_of_functions)
```

so we get as return another dataframe with bool values for each timeframe (columns) per function (index):

```
                       TF1    TF2   TF3   TF4    TF5   TF6    TF7    TF8    TF9   TF10   TF11   TF12   TF13
sum_greater_than_100  True  False  True  True  False  True   True  False   True  False  False   True   True
mean_greater_than_5   True  False  True  True  False  True   True  False   True  False  False  False  False
std_less_than_3       True  False  True  True   True  True  False   True  False   True   True   True  False
```

Finally, we can easily sum up the columns to get the result on how many functions passed by timeframe:

```py
df_pass.sum()
```

```
TF1     3
TF2     0
TF3     3
TF4     3
TF5     1
TF6     3
TF7     2
TF8     1
TF9     2
TF10    1
TF11    1
TF12    2
TF13    1
```

Comment: Wow, this is definitely impressive code for summing up the data and analyzing multiple function from a list.  However, I have to show more clarity for the sample data frame as a starting point and end up where you have finished.

Comment: @Max Couto-Silva The sample data would be looping through DataFrames that have been grouped for lets say 1.) sum_greater_than_100, 2.) mean_greater_than_5, and 3.) std_less_than_3.  After that they are  grouped for each TimeFrame, ( TF1    TF2   TF3   TF4    TF5   TF6    TF7    TF8    TF9   TF10   TF11   TF12   TF13). Then we apply multple function to get result

Comment: @Max Couto-Silva  Another way to understand what I am saying is that instead of values in the sample data_frame you have above, each value in that data_frame would be a data_frame for ex.(instead of 6.964692 as a value it is df_MD1-TF1 data_frame being sent to a function for a True / False).  I have my code producing the data_frames properly, but sending each df into the various functions to populate a new df_like you have is my challenge.

Comment: Do your functions take a whole dataframe and return a True/False value? Do you have this working? So you have a list of dataframes you'll apply the functions, is that it?

Comment: Max Couto-Silva. Yes, I am producing a list of df's and want the output df format you have above.  The name of the df represents the Columns and the Rows, ex. for just MD1 would be ( df_MD1-TF1, df_MD1-TF2, df_MD1-TF3............df_MD1-TF13)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pivot tables fit what you want to do better than groupby, but without your data it's difficult to say exactly what the code should be.